# Alternative Address Book API helper to ABContact

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, abaddressbook, reference-counting

I have an Iphone app that used the excellent  ABContactHelper library origionally written for by [Erica Sedun and released on github](https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper)

Now with the release of XCode4 and Reference Counting support, it causes lots of errors.  I have looked at the forks on github, but none seem to have updated to XCode 4 with Reference Counting.  I am trying to update it myself but its slow and error prone.  I have tried the automatic refactoring support, but to no avail.

Does anyone know of an alternative AddressBook wrapper that provides a simple interface for interacting with the IPhone AddressBook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your ARC-enabled project, you can selectively disable ARC for the AddressBook wrapper files by setting the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for those files.

Add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. Enter the compiler flag by double-clicking on the right column of the row under Compiler Flags.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with ARC/non-ARC issues is a pain in the butt, and I've found that letting CocoaPods handle these problems for me is the way to go. Simply list ABContactHelper as a pod dependency and you're done. Many of the most popular libraries are already there, but if yours isn't, it's really easy to add it.

http://cocoapods.org